# WxPython perform action for a specific choice of ComboBox-Selection

Tags: python, wxpython

I wan't to perform an action if a specific entry of a ComboBox is selected AND the ComboBox loosing the focus.

I know how to call a handler via

```
 self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.__HandlerForComboBox, mycombobox)
```

but the problem is:
if the user click through the ComboBox-choices via arrow up/arrow down he will be pass the element and the action will performend. So I thought about combining this handler with something like `looseFocus`(only the specific ComboBox), and the action will only performed if the specific choice in the ComboBox is selected AND the user entered this by clicking out of the ComboBox or clicking tabulator to go away from this Box.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `HandlerForComboBox`, just set a flag that your specific entry has been chosen. Something like this should work:

```
if self.cbo.GetValue() == 'special value':
    self.special_entry = True
else:
    self.special_entry = False
```

Then in your focus event handler, you just check to see if `self.special_entry` is True and act accordingly.